# Aurelia How to get to function of composed child pages

Tags: aurelia

I have a parent form that loads child forms into tabs.
The parent looks like this:

```
<div repeat.for="app of Apps">
    <compose if.bind='app.Url.startsWith("modules/")' view-model="${app.Url}"></compose>
</div>
```

So each of the "compose" tags loads a different page based on URL.
How can I find the specific page and call a function from that page's ts file?

I have a temporary solution in place by, on the parent, declaring a variable with:
`childPage: any;`
and then on the activate event of the child, I do:
`parent.childPage = this;`
Then, on the parent page, I have can do:
`childPage.childFunction();`

This of course doesn't give me intellisense and won't work with multiple children, but for now, it meets my needs.

Comment: What error do you see, if any, when this code runs?

Comment: you can use the event aggregator to emit an event on the parent page - the child in the compose can react to that event a run the function.

Comment: @AshleyGrant, I'm not getting errors.  The code I posted above works fine.  Let me try to clarify.  Let's say my outer div has 4 apps in which case, that compose will loop 4 times and I'll have 4 different viewmodels/pages.  I'm trying to find a way from viewmodel4 to execute a function that is in viewmodel1.

Comment: @avrahamcool, I've tried with event aggregator and it didn't seem to get me where I needed to be.  I will look into it further.

Comment: It might more helpful if you can explain your exact scenario. Considering you pass both model and view-model in compose, you can delegate the task to the view model shown in the tab. If that is not possible, event aggregator should also work as suggested by @avrahamcool. People will be able to suggest better if you can explain you exact scenario, and/or why neither of the suggested approaches work.